# read fasta file and compute DNA gc content

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

First, I want to say that I am new to python programming. I spent nearly 20 hours for figuring  this out, however, my code is still frustrating. I have a fasta file which comprise of ID and DNA sequence. I would like to read in the FASTA data and do some computational work.

The FASTA file reads like this:

```
>1111886
AACGAACGCTGGCGGCATGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAACGA…
>1111885
AGAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAATGAACGCTGGCGGCGTGCCT…
>1111883
GCTGGCGGCGTGCCTAACACATGTAAGTCGAACGGGACTGGG…
```

I wrote the following code to read in the fasta data and do some analysis such as compute gc content by ID, average sequence length ,etc. I put the detailed description for what I want to do in docstring. I appreciate anyone who can improve my code, especially how to get gc content for each ID.

```
class fasta(object):
def __init__(self, filename):
    self.filename = filename
    self.num_sequences = None
    self.sequences = {} #{seq_id} = sequence

def parse_file(self):
    **"""Reads in the sequence data contained in the filename associated with this  instance of the class.
    Stores both the sequence and the optional comment for each ID."""**
    with open(self.filename) as f:
        return f.read().split('>')[1:]
def get_info(self):
    **"""Returns a description of the class in a pretty string format. 
    The description should include the filename for the instance and the number of sequences."""**
    for line in file(self.filename, 'r'):
        if line.startswith('>'):
            self.num_sequences += 1
    return self.num_sequences
def compute_gc_content(self,some_id):
    **"""compute the gc conent for sequence ID some_id. If some_id, return an appropriate error values"""**
    baseFrequency = {}
    for line in file(self.filename, 'r'):
        if not line.startswith(">"):
        for base in sequence:
            baseFrequency[base] = baseFrequency.get(base,0)+1
            items = baseFrequency.items()
            items.sort()
        for i in items:
            gc=(baseFrequency['G'] + baseFrequency['C'])/float(len(sequence))
    return gc

def sequence_statistics(self):
      **"""returns a dictionary containing
         The average sequence length
         The average gc content"""**
    baseFrequency = {}
    for line in file(self.filename, 'r'):
        if not line.startswith(">"):
        for base in sequence:
            baseFrequency[base] = baseFrequency.get(base,0)+1
            items = baseFrequency.items()
            items.sort()
        for i in items:
            gc=(baseFrequency['G'] + baseFrequency['C'])/float(len(sequence))
            aveseq=sum(len(sequence))/float(self.count)
    return (gc,aveseq) 


def get_all_kmers(self, k=8):
    **"""get all kmer counts of size k in fasta file. Returns a dictionary with keys equal to the kmers
    and values equal to the counts"""**
    t={}
    for x in range (len(self.sequence)+1-k):
        kmer=self.sequence[x:x+k]
        t[kmer]=f.get(kmer,0)+1
        kmers = get_all_kmers(k=8)
    return(t,len(kmers))

def query_sequence_id(self, some_id):
    **"""query sequence ids for some_id. If some_id does not exist in the class, return
    a string error message"""**
    for line in file(self.filename, 'r'):
    if id in line:
        print "The id exists"
    else:
        print "The id does not exist"
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use libraries?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Typically reg-ex's are used for the type of pattern matching you described.

Comment: Have you considered using [Biopython](http://biopython.org)? Read through the tutorial, IIRC it has functions built-in for computing GC content, and it parses FASTA files quite easily.

Comment: I read some material about biopython, however, I am not allowed to use that.

Comment: So what is working, not working here? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I think my code does not work for some reason. I would like to ask someone for help to improve my code. I spent a lot of time doing this

Comment: You must have a reason for thinking so. what did you test? what was the output or error messages you got? what did you expect\want to see?

Comment: I tried to test my code using the pasta file ex_ref.fasta, but I did not get the file to read in

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to read and parse your file. saving it in a dictionary with the id as keys, and info\data as a sub dictionary for each id.

Please ask if you don't understand all of this.

```
def parse_file(self):
    """Reads in the sequence data contained in the filename associated with this  instance of the class.
    Stores both the sequence and the optional comment for each ID."""

    def parser(filename):
        seq = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('>'):
                    if seq: 
                        yield seqId, seqInfo, ''.join(seq)
                    line = line.split()
                    seqId = line[0][1:]
                    if len(line) > 1:
                        seqInfo = ' '.join(line[1:])
                    else:
                        seqInfo = ''
                    seq = []
                else:
                    seq.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
        if seq:
            yield seqId, seqInfo, ''.join(seq)

    sequences = parser(self.filename)

    self.sequences = {sequenceId: {'info': sequenceInfo, 'data': sequenceData}  for (sequenceId, sequenceInfo, sequenceData) in sequences}
```